# Указатель цели в 2d пространстве

Tags: unity3d

Использую указатель цели, как одна из механик игры, в данный момент указатель работает, но бегает четко по границам экрана, хотелось бы сделать отступ и добавить вращение стрелки в зависимости от того где находится цель(низ, верх, право, лево)

```
        Vector3 targetOnScreen = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(target.GetComponent<Transform>().position);
        targetOnScreen.x = Mathf.Clamp01(targetOnScreen.x);
        targetOnScreen.y = Mathf.Clamp01(targetOnScreen.y);

        if (target.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().isVisible)
        {
            arrow.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else arrow.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        arrow.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(targetOnScreen);
```

Comment: `Vector3 v_diff = (target.transform.position - _Player.transform.position);
            float atan2 = Mathf.Atan2(v_diff.y, v_diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

            arrow.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, atan2 - 180);

            arrow.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(arrow.position, target.transform.position, 1000);

            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(arrow.position);

            pos.x = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.x);
            pos.y = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.y);

            arrow.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(pos);`

Comment: Сделал вращение, но индикатор всё так же на границе экрана